# htaccess rewrite rule for subdomains with page id

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

i want to redirect

http://subdomain.example.com/index.php?pageID=45

to

http://example.com/subdomain/45.html

Please help me with this

i tried

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/sudomain/$1 [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your code by this one in your htaccess (in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageID=([1-9][0-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/subdomain/%1.html? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The code is working and it is showing '?pageID=45' again at the end. i appreciate your time & help

Comment: Sorry for that, i edited my answer to avoid that behaviour. Simply add `?` after `%1.html` (see the new code)